# how can i know which event is called in which activity?

Tags: android, events, activity-monitor

I want to create an activity monitor program which monitors activities and their events as specified.

Can you please tell me how can I know which event in a running activity is being executed? How can I collect data related to clicks or swipes in the same activity i.e. which button or menu is being clicked.

Comment: i think you are talking about android... but still it is advised to add the proper relevant tags

Comment: Yes I was talking about Android.

Comment: if you want to monitor inside the app you can override some functions..

Comment: Hi Patato.. please tell about class and function..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the running activity name by using-

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

I used above code many times to find running activity name in my App.

Try below code to find the pressed button information,

```
public void onClick(View view) {         
    Button b1 = (Button)view;
    String text = b1.getText().toString();
}
```